# Network error when trying to launch a node on an other machine

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, network, network-setup, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

My distribution is ros-kinetic and I am using ubuntu 16.04 on both machines

I am trying to run a node on a second machine (a realsense camera node) by adding this lines in my launch file:

```
<group>
<machine name="suitee" address="192.168.0.100" default="true" />
<include file="$(find s_bringup)/launch/rs_aligned_depth.launch" machine="suitee"/>
</group>
```

I have followed the network setup tutorial here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup

Specifically, I have the following variables set on my master machine (where roscore is ran):

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.0.142
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://${ROS_HOSTNAME}:11311
```

I have these set on my slave machine:

```
export ROS_IP=192.168.0.100
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.0.142:11311
```

I also respectively modified the /etc/hosts file on both machines:

For master : 192.168.0.100   suitee

For slave: 192.168.0.142   suitee2

I can ping both machines correctly from each other.

However when I try to run my launch file, I get the following error:

```
started roslaunch server http://192.168.0.142:42619/
remote[192.168.0.100-0] starting roslaunch
remote[192.168.0.100-0]: creating ssh connection to 192.168.0.100:22
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py:141: FutureWarning: CTR mode needs counter parameter, not IV
self._cipher = factory.new(key, *args, **kwargs)
remote[192.168.0.100-0]: failed to launch on suitee:

Unable to establish ssh connection to [192.168.0.100:22]: Server u'192.168.0.100' not found in known_hosts


[192.168.0.100-0] killing on exit
unable to start remote roslaunch child: 192.168.0.100-0
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I have tried to remove the know_hosts files and connect via ssh and I can connect from both machines using:

```
ssh suitee@192.168.0.100
ssh suitee2@192.168.0.142
```

EDIT: I can correctly see all topics on both machines and I i launch the node manually on the slave card, I can see the published topics correctly and it seems to have no problems to find the master.

Can anyone help me on this ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339788/network-error-when-trying-to-launch-a-node-on-an-other-machine/) by [Alrevan](https://answers.ros.org/users/48145/alrevan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2019-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally found the answer for this issue:

I had to add the tag "user" into the launch file:

```
<group>
<machine name="suitee" address="192.168.0.100" default="true" user="suitee" />
<include file="$(find s_bringup)/launch/rs_aligned_depth.launch" machine="suitee"/>
</group>
```

I also had to follow the answer here:
https://answers.ros.org/question/41446/a-is-not-in-your-ssh-known_hosts-file/

---

Originally posted by [Alrevan](https://answers.ros.org/users/48145/alrevan/) with karma: 126 on 2019-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0